# How to manually configure touchpad and non-Apple mouse in Mac OS through plist editing (without third-party software)?

Tags: mac, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, mouse-buttons

I have a Logitech bluetooth mouse that I use with a work MacBook. I cannot install mouse configuration third-party software per IT security policy (not worth recommending any of them, I simply can't install anything), but I would like to achieve the following:

1. Touchpad:

- Scroll using "natural" scrolling directions.

2. External mouse:

- Scroll using "un-natural" scrolling directions, i.e., scroll using the intuitive directions for a scrolling wheel — the mouse has both vertical and horizontal scroll wheels.
- Configure the main 2 extra buttons, that work and are currently assigned to "forward" and "back" (they work as such in browsers at least), "copy" and "paste".

I suppose I could use terminal commands and/or modify plist files (listed below), but I'm not sure exactly how.

Mouse Preference Files:

- com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist
- com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
- com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist

Trackpad Preference Files:

- com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist
- com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist

(Question " [Utilize extra mouse buttons in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/1140403/utilize-extra-mouse-buttons-in-mac-os-x) " does not answer my question)

Comment: Why can't you use `System Settings > Trackpad` to at least adjust the scroll direction of your trackpad?

Comment: Because when I change it for the trackpad it also changes for the mouse and vice-versa, which always makes one of them to be unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plist editor. Just run the app from the download folder without installing.

For back and next button.
com.apple.driver.apple.AppleHIDMouse
Button3 1
Button4 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).